# Запрос, сделанный браузером, и запрос, сделанный HttpURLConnection, дают разный результат

Tags: java, http, url, httpurlconnection

Делаю и браузером и сторонними сайтами запрос:

(с сайта https://www.hurl.it/)

```
GET https://*********

HEADERS
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: runscope/0.1
```

Получаю ответ: `302 Moved Temporarily`. Все как надо.

Теперь делаю такой же запрос на Java (для чистоты эксперимента скопировал все заголовки):

```
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://*****").openConnection();
 connection.setRequestProperty("Accept"," */*");
 connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
 connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "runscope/0.1");
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
 StringBuilder page = new StringBuilder();
 String read;
 while ((read = in.readLine()) != null)
        page.append(read);
 System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
```

Получаю ответ `200`. Проверял и на других запросах. Плюс по этому запросу сайт должен выслать set-cookies, он их не высылает для Java. Что не так?

**UPD.** Только что сделать запрос вручную, через сокет. Получил `302`, как и должно быть. Что не так с этим `HttpURLConnection`? Может кто нибудь подскажет, как посмотреть что он вообще в итоге отправляет серверу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию в `HttpURLConnection` установлено

```
/* do we automatically follow redirects? The default is true. */
private static boolean followRedirects = true;
```

Т.е. все запросы вернувшие 3хх будут перезапрошены по новому адресу.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://*****").openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept"," */*");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "runscope/0.1");

int status = connection.getResponseCode();
// тут можно проанализировать код
// дальше идет код который подразумевает, что было перенаправление

// новый URL
String newUrl = connection.getHeaderField("Location"); 
// полученные куки
String cookies = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept"," */*");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "runscope/0.1");    
// дальше можно делать как делали вы
```

Если вам хочется большего контроля над ситуацией, то стоит использовать HttpClient, например [Apache Http Client Library](http://hc.apache.org/)

Comment: Как же до меня сразу не дошло ) Вырубил этот редирект через connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); и всё нормально, спасибо )

Comment: @Uraty я немного расширил пример